# CouchDB's replicated DB is a copy or reference to original?

Tags: ionic-framework, couchdb, replication, pouchdb, couchdb-futon

As per http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/replication.html

> Replication synchronizes two copies of the same database, allowing
>   users to have low latency access to data no matter where they are.
>   These databases can live on the same server or on two different
>   servers—CouchDB doesn’t make a distinction. If you change one copy of
>   the database, replication will send these changes to the other copy.

I have following 2 confisions:

1. Does this mean that every replicated DB is a new DB/copy of original DB or does it refers to the original DB?
2. On replication will it increase the size of DB?

**Note:** These confusions are in context of PouchDB(mobile) to CouchDB(server) interactions. To be more precise, I want to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/32206581/2904573

Have also gone through https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766398/2904573 but didn't got my answer.

Comment: As far as I know, the replicated DB is NOT a symbolic link to the original DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question on CouchDB github repo and got the answer.

> The replicated DB is a new copy. In the most general terms, it takes
>   all the documents and attachments in the original DB (called the
>   source) and puts them into a new DB (called the target).
>
> If the replication is a continuous replication, then the source is
>   also then monitored for any new changes, and, if they are any, those
>   change are copied to the target as well.

Ref: https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1494#issuecomment-410933908

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the replicated DB is NOT a symbolic link to original DB, but it's a duplicate.